QField using a Trimble R1 doesn't work even though connected
I'm using QField version 3.3.11 on an Android Tablet and a Trimble R1 as GNSS antenna. I am able to connect to the antenna in QField correctly but afterwards... just nothing happens, positioning within QField just doesn't show anything (even though the Trimble R1) shows the proper status lights and seems to be working.
I tried with both Mock locations off and on (configured in the Mobile Manager App by Trimble). If only accessed by the Mobile Manager app, the Trimble works without issues.
Any ideas on how to approach that, either QField or Mock location related problem?
Disclaimer: It used to work with the same tablet and the same Trimble some months ago, but in the meantime Android, Mobile Manager and Qfield were updated to new versions.
EDIT: I now also tried the Android NTRIP lient as App fpr moc locations. Configured it correctly, it's working. When i try to connect to the Antenna in QField though, it refuses the connection with "Positioning Device error: Network error during read (NetworkError)"
